# Como criar um botão para somar mais um no valor do editText?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de uma apoio de vcs...
Eu estou tentando adicionar um botão para subtrair e incluir a quantidade de itens...

Vejam meu código... já tentei algumas maneira, porém sem sucesso. Tem que ser pelo EditText

```
package com.example.trabalhohomecompras;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Linha extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numero = 0;
    //private Button btnMais1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linha);

        Button btnMais1 = findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);
        btnMais1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                numero = numero + 1; // adiciona +1 na váriavel numero
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_teste);

                t.setText(String.valueOf(numero));
                System.out.print(numero);

                //TextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero))); // coloca o valor na textview
                //EditText simpleEditText =  findViewById(R.id.edit_cont);

                //System.out.println(numero);
                //simpleEditText.setText(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero)));
                //simpleEditText.setText(numero);
            }

        });


    }
}
```

[image: print]

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua ideia for atualizar os valores
Você precisa fazer o **findViewById()`** do **EditText** para pegar a sua referência.

E você fará as atualizações nesse EditText.

```
    public class Linha extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        int numero = 0;
        private Button btnMais1;
        private EditText txtQuantidade;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.linha);

          EditText quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_quantidade);

          Button btnMais1 = findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);
          btnMais1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                numero = numero + 1; // adiciona +1 na váriavel numero
                quantidade.setText(String.valueOf(numero));

                System.out.print(numero);
            }

        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Tentei implementar dessa forma tbm não foi...

Comment: Parece que não funciona o onclik, ou a varialvel ou o edite não recebem nada no meu código...

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.trabalhohomecompras;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Linha extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numero = 0;
    //private Button btnMais1;
    private Button btnMais1;
    private EditText txtQuantidade;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linha);

        //EditText qtd;
        txtQuantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cont);
        btnMais1 = findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Descricao);
        btnMais1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                numero = numero + 1; // adiciona +1 na váriavel numero
                //TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_teste);
                txtQuantidade.setText(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero)));
                t.setText(String.valueOf(numero));
                System.out.print(numero);

                //TextView.setText(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero))); // coloca o valor na textview
                //EditText simpleEditText =  findViewById(R.id.edit_cont);

                //System.out.println(numero);
                //simpleEditText.setText(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numero)));
                //simpleEditText.setText(numero);
            }

        });


    }

}
```

Testei diversas maneiras, mas tbm não foi...

Answer (score 0):

Todo componente de tela deve ser atribuído no método `onCreate()` utilizando `findViewById` (existem métodos mais modernos, mas não se preocupe com isso agora).

Para atribuição de +1 utilize o operador `++`.

`t.setText` espera uma `string`, e numero é `int`. Realize a conversão utilizando `String.valueOf`, por exemplo.

Em Java, não realize a conversão dentro do `t.setText()` ele geralmente reclama disso.

```
public class Linha extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numero = 0;
    //private Button btnMais1;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linha);
    
    // Todos elemento de tela que irá fazer uso findViewById deve ser declarado dentro do onCreate
    
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_teste);
        Button btnMais1 = findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);
        
    btnMais1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        
        // Add +1 em numero
        numero++;
        
        // Converter Int em String
        String converterNumero = String.valueOf(numero);
                
        //Informe o novo numero.
        t.setText(converterNumero);
                
            }
    
        });
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Fazendo isso que vc orientou ai me retorna que devo criar um getT para a variavel t.setText

Comment: t.setText(converterNumero); Nessa parte do código alega que deve "Extract Method" ai da duas opções de fazer o getT fora do o onClik ou dentro dele.